# Data Profiling/ Analysis Tool in marklogic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

I am working on a use case where I will be loading the source data into marklogic with csv/excel/pdf format "as-is". Later we need to do the data profiling/analysis using some tool in marklogic. Doing some search on google, I see a tool named "data analyzer" in some of the blogs. There is no information or GitHub project around data analyzer tool.

Please help if anyone aware of data analyzer or any of the data profiling/ analysis tools in marklogic.

Answer (score 0):

Data Analyzer is a legacy tool MarkLogic built internally for doing simple data profiling. It was never intended for wide public release or ever open sourced.

Personally, I use the MarkLogic Slush application for basic data profiling and analysis: https://github.com/marklogic-community/slush-marklogic-node

Please get in touch with your MarkLogic account team for an official recommendation on the best available tool for your data profiling needs.